# A CSV reader for an adjacency matrix?

Tags: c

I need a CSV reader that will output a NxN (weighted) adjacency matrix (N is not known from the beginning). Of course I can use strtok() and friends to parse this, but if something is already available and complete enough, I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could use [this](http://code.google.com/p/csv-routine/) as base if you don't find anything better, it should be fairly simple to modify to handle NxN. It works by reading the whole file into a buffer, then sets pointers into the buffer by finding the delimiters and settings those to \0.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply